# GUI based debugging tools using DWARF information from ELF file

Tags: gcc, elf, dwarf

I am searching for a GUI based debugging tool which reads DWARF info from ELF file and maps the assembly instructions to the line number of the source code. Are there any such tools existing, please let me know?

Comment: Did you try GDB? Why do you need a GUI based tool? What OS should host the GUI program? What have your TRIED?

Comment: @harper I need GUI so that it would be easy to browse the code and compare assembly instructions at the same time(in same GUI terminal), not by opening two separate terminals one to map the assembly code and get source code line number and other to browse the source code, as we work with "addr2line" utility. I tried "addr2line" utility but as i told before, its not user friendly. Regarding OS, linux is preferred, but any OS should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

There are many gdb GUIs.  There is a [reasonably complete list](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends) on the GDB Wiki.  For best results, pick one from the first ("Using modern GDB/MI") category.